# Option to hide explorer action icons in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to hide explorer action icons? (Other way than using custom-css extension).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, coming to vscode v1.72 will be the ability to hide any of those icons.  Deminstrating in the Insiders Build v1.72:

[image: hide Explorer view buttons]

> ###### Hide actions from tool bars
>
> You can now hide actions from tool bars. Simply right-click on any
> action in a tool bar and select its hide-command or any of the toggle
> commands. Hidden actions will be moved to the ... menu and can be
> invoked from there. To restore a menu select the "Reset Menu" command,
> to store all menus select "F1 > Reset All Menus".

from [v1.72 Release Notes: hide actions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#hide-actions-from-tool-bars)